# Ros2 foxy explore_lite package requested and data time error

Tags: ros2

I am using https://github.com/robo-friends/m-explore-ros2 this repo to implement explore_lite package to ros2 foxy. When I try this package with turtlebot, it works great. But when i use my own project and my own world. There is requested and data time error which can be seen below. There is a huge difference between times and i dont know why. When i check the ros2 topic echo /tf i can see the publishing data very clearly. The data value(119.801) always matched with the echo tf lists and it's unit in second

Extrapolation Error looking up robot pose: Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 1700418376.067588 but the latest data is at time 119.801000, when looking up transform from frame [base_link] to frame [map]

The command that i use:

1. ros2 launch my_bot launch_sim.launch.py (this is launch my robot in gazebo)
2. rviz2
3. ros2 launch nav2_bringup slam_launch.py use_sim_time:=true
4. ros2 launch nav2_bringup navigation_launch.py use_sim_time:=true
5. ros2 run explore_lite explore --ros-args --params-file <path_to_ros_ws>/m-explore-ros2/explore/config/params.yaml(this starts explore_lite.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very large difference in timestamps looks like some of your system is running on simulated time and some is running on system time(Aka wall clock time). It's likely that you are running some of your nodes without sim time selected by the parameter.